# Difference between pipe open '|' and '|-' (safe pipe open)

Tags: linux, perl, pipe

I have seen these two forms of pipe `open` in perl.

One is simple pipe open

```
open FH,'| command';
```

and other is safe pipe open

```
open FH,'|-','command';
```

Now, What is the use of `-` in second one? They both write to pipe. I know that `-` forks new process.

Does simple `|` also creates new process?

When will/should we use safe pipe open `|-`?

Comment: I am not from perl background in but most programming `|` is bitwise operator, `-` is unary negation, see `i = 5 | 6` then `|-` is `i = 5 | -6` that is `5` or with `-6`. And I found [`| in pearl`  is bitwise](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-operators.html)..Am I correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan in this case no.

Comment: @PSIAlt Yes its `|-` is `"the filename is interpreted as a command to which output is to be piped"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `-` when you plan to(you want to) pipe from a fork of yourself (`-|`) or to a fork of yourself `|-`. The `open` function returns the child's process ID in the parent process and 0 in the child process. Example:

```
if( open(TO, "|-") ) {
    # Parent process
    print TO $from_parent;
}
else {
    # Child process
    $to_child = <STDIN>;
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between

```
 open my $PIPE, '| command';
```

vs

```
 open my $PIPE, '|-', 'command';
```

The "safe" open is actually

```
 open my $PIPE, '|-', 'program', @one_or_more_args;
```

This version is guaranteed to launch program directly; no shell is invoked. It also saves you from having to turn arguments into shell literals. In other words,

```
 open my $FH, '|-', 'program', @one_or_more_args;
```

is similar to

```
 use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
 open my $FH, '|'.shell_quote('program', @one_or_more_args);
```

but without the shell (so less resources are wasted, you get the program's PID instead of a shell's, and you get to know if the program died from a signal).

Unfortunately, there's no syntax for a program with zero args like there is for `system`.

(There's also `open my $PIPE, "|-"` with no further args, but that's something else.)

Comment: apparently,there is. `|-` creates a child. Now when you write to the filehandle, the child gets it in its STDIN.

Comment: @Drt, Are you confusing `open my $PIPE, '|-';` for either `open my $PIPE, '| command';`, `open my $PIPE, '|-', 'command';` or  `open my $PIPE, '|-', 'program', @one_or_more_args;`?

Comment: I meant, when/why is safe pipe open better or used than the other one?

Comment: It's not safe vs unsafe. As I explained, it's shell command vs prog and args. It's better to avoid the shell when you don't need it. It's better to use the shell when you need it.

Comment: I don't know what you read, but there's no such thing as safe pipes; there's only one kind of pipe. As I explained, it's shell command vs prog and args. (Or just a fork in the case of `|-` with no further args.) It's better to avoid the shell when you don't need it. It's better to use the shell when you need it.

Comment: What about it? That has nothing to do with your question, and it doesn't contradict anything I said. Again, please form sentences. Are you trying to troll?

Comment: Why are you avoiding to call `|-` pipe open as safe-pipe-open? What you wrote is correct, but that's what is called safe-pipe-open(i.e. `|-`). In that link, it's also given, why it's called safe.

Comment: Cause it's not. That link does not call `open(my $pipe, '|-')` "safe-pipe-open". Furthermore, it's off-topic. You're question does not ask about `open(my $pipe, '|-')`.

Comment: That linked section is describing how to have a privileged script run code that doesn't need the elevated privileges by creating a subprocess linked by a pipe. It has absolutely nothing to do with `open`. It's jsut using it as a convenient way of creating a pipe and forking.

Comment: From that link: `open(PS_PIPE, "-|", "ps", "aux");` Here we are using string literals whose content is perfectly safe. There is therefore no cause to resort to the harder-to-read, multi-argument form of pipe open(). However, whenever you cannot be assured that the program arguments are free of shell metacharacters, the fancier form of open() should be used. `open(GREP_PIPE, "-|", @grep_args)`.

Comment: That means it is calling arguments in first form as safe and in second it is saying args are unsafe. And hence recommending to use three-arg open. So in case of safe, it's saying you can use simple open as `open FH,"| ps aux"`. and for second it is recommending to use `open FH,"|-", @grep_args`, because args could contain metachars

Comment: I covered this already. Many times. Please read my answer. If you're going to ignore it, fine, but stop askingme to repeat it.

Comment: They call `"cat $file"` unsafe, but it's not unsafe, it's just plain wrong.

Comment: @ikegami - are these comments worth keeping or do you want them removed?

Comment: You would want to skip using shell when you really don't need it to avoid unexpected shell expansions taking place and improve security against script injections.